# Duplicating turtle list elements by n for every loop iteration

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

I have a list of turtle elements that I want to double by the end of each loop, but it returns nothing

```
level = 1

number_of_enemies = 5
enemies = []
for i in range(number_of_enemies):`
    enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())

 while True:
    for level < 4
         [for enemy in l for enemies in repeat(enemy, level)] 
         for enemy in enemies: 
              (do_stuff)
    level += 1
```

Comment: You should give more details about exactly what you are trying to accomplish, however, your problem likely stems from the fact that you aren't doing anything with your list comprehension, just creating a list then throwing it away because you never assign it to a variable!

Comment: By the end of the first loop, there shoud be 5, then 10, then 15.

Comment: Right, I'm not sure how you think your code accomplishes that, but I suspect you are confused by your list comprehension, which again, achieves nothing because you never assign the resulting list to a variable, and that list is simply discarded.

Comment: So, one way to double your enemies each time in the for-loop would be to do this:`enemies += [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(len(enemies))]`

Comment: It looks like your while loop is indented one space more than your for loop. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yeah, but there's a break further down

Answer (score 0):

Generate a number of enemies double the then length of enemies list through `enemies = [generate_turtle_object_somehow for i in range(2*l)]`. Also, list comprehension returns a result list, so it needs to be assigned appropriately.
Code:

```
level = 1
turtle = "turtle"
number_of_enemies = 5
enemies = []
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    enemies.append(turtle+str(i+1))
#print enemies

while level < 4:
    print "level", level
    l = len(enemies)
    enemies = [turtle+str(i+1) for i in range(2*l)]
    print enemies
    print len(enemies)
    for enemy in enemies: 
        pass
    level += 1
```